# How to find out unused C++ class/struct member variable

Tags: c++

The short version of the question is: how to find if a member variable of a class/struct is never used in any .cpp file so that I can remove the member variable.

Some background story:

Suppose I have a struct to store all config values of my program:

```
struct Configs {
    ConfigValue<int> Config1 = ConfigValue<int>("Config1Name", 10);
    ConfigValue<std::string> Config2 = ConfigValue<std::string>("Config2Name", "SomeDefaultValue");
    // And many other configs...
};
```

Each config variable is an object of `ConfigValue` class:

```
template<class T>
class ConfigValue {
private:
    std::string m_configName;
    T m_value;
public:
    ConfigValue(const std::string& configName, const T& defaultValue) : m_configName(configName), m_value(defaultValue) {
        Refresh();
    }

    void Refresh() {
        // Refresh `m_value` from some config file using `m_configName`.
    }

    T Get() const {
        return m_value;
    }
};
```

To read a config value, the user needs an object of `Configs`, and call `Get` function:

```
    Configs configs;
    int config1Value = configs.Config1.Get();
```

There are a lot of .cpp files reading different config values from `struct Configs`. As the code is changing over time, some configs are never used anymore. To find them out and remove them, there are a few ways:

- Try removing each of the config from `struct Configs`, compile all .cpp files and see if there's any build failure. But since there are so many configs now, this way is not very efficient, and will become less efficient as more configs are added.
- Try string search in .cpp files and .h files. But this is not very reliable as the string may occur in comments, or there might be another variable/function with the same name as the config.
- Try using DUMPBIN command on each of the .obj file compiled from .cpp files. But the configs are all member variable in `Struct Configs` (they are not functions), I believe when the configs variables are accessed, only the offset from `Struct Configs` is used. So I can't find symbol with the same name as the config variable.

Is there a better way?

Comment: ...Use an IDE with usage search?

Comment: Are you sure you want a big-ass table of all configuration values? You might find it easier to maintain if you broke it down to at least a package or module level. After all, package Foo doesn't give a crap (or shouldn't give a crap) about the configuration of package Foo.

Comment: Besides the duplicate question, you can also use ` -Wunused-private-field` as long as the field is private, or `clang-diagnostic-unused-private-field` in clang-tidy. These warnings could be displayed to you in your IDE, so that may be a better workflow then compiling and seeing if it breaks.